# How does foreach cast without explicit/implicit overrides?

Tags: c#, casting, foreach

So I'm just learning C#, and came across something that I find odd... I'm playing with delegates and have creates a delegate *DelegateReturnsInt*. Now, When I use a **foreach** loop, the book shows to use it like this:

```
foreach(DelegateReturnsInt del in theDelegate.getInvocationList())
```

now I know that getInvocationList() returns an Array of Delegate[], but how does it convert them to *DelegateReturnsInt*? I ask because I wanted to just play around and change it from a foreach to a for loop, so I created this

```
Delegate[] del = theDelegate.GetInvocationList();
for(int i = 0; i < del.Length; i++){
    int result = del[i]();
```

but that doesn't see del[i] as a method. I've tried casting to *DelegateReturnsInt* and such, but it gives me cast type errors about not having it defined.

My big question is what makes foreach() so special?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It does an implicit cast (if you look at the emitted IL, you'd see it).  This also means you could get an unexpected cast exception on that line if it's not what you say it is.

Comment: Delegate[] del = theDelegate.GetInvocationList();
for(int i = 0; i < del.Length; i++) {
DelegateReturnsInt temp = (DelegateReturnsInt) del[i];
}

Yup, that works now. It was throwing Errors before, which was why I asked. Thanks for the explanation

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/530748/new-fxcop-rule-for-net2-on-foreach-in-non-generic-ienumerable

Comment: Yes exactly, there is an "invisible" or "implicit" cast present in a `foreach` (except if you use `var` in the `foreach` which I really recommend). This cast is invisible, but it works with both implicit type conversions and explicit type conversions. For example the reference conversion from the base type `Delegate` to the derived type `DelegateReturnsInt` (a downcast) is an _explicit reference conversion_ in C# terminology. So the "invisible" cast works for explicit conversions as well (may throw `InvalidCastException` at run-time or course).