# Why var used in foreach for XmlNode does not deduce real type, only object?

Tags: c#, types, foreach, var

Let `cls` be of type `XmlNode`

Following statement allows me to access child nodes:

```
foreach (XmlNode child in cls.ChildNodes)
```

Now when I try to use var:

```
foreach (var child in cls.ChildNodes)
```

then the type of child is not `XmlNode`, only *object*. I cannot use `child.NodeType`, compiler says:

> *object' does not contain a definition for 'NodeType*

Why is this?

Comment: Add cast to (XmlNode)child inside your loop.

Comment: No, don't. That is a terrible advice. The first foreach statement is the correct one to be used.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does foreach cast without explicit/implicit overrides?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471717/how-does-foreach-cast-without-explicit-implicit-overrides)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ChildNodes` is of type `XmlNodeList` which is defined as

```
public abstract class XmlNodeList : IEnumerable, IDisposable
```

Its enumerator returns an `object`. When you use `XmlNode` instead of `var`, .net automatically `casts` object to `XmlNode`. But when you use `var`, child is treated as an object.

Comment: `Its enumerator returns an object`.  From what part of that class declaration do you derive this statement?

Comment: @DonBoitnott If `XmlNodeList` implements `IEnumerable` and not `IEnumerable<XmlNode>` then it must enumerate objects when you use `foreach` with an instance of that type.

Comment: It only implements `IEnumerable` which returns an `IEnumerator` from `GetEnumerator()` method whose `Current` property, which is used in foreach iterations, is an object. In short since it is not implementing `IEnumerable<XmlNode>` it returns items as objects in foreach iterations.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Well ... If we want to be pedantic, if the type contains a public non-static non-genric zero-parameter method `GetEnumerator()`, then the return type of that method is investigated and its propery `Current` gives the type. For example `System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection` is defined with only non-generic interfaces, as `public class StringCollection : IList, ICollection, IEnumerable`. Still if I have `StringCollection nodes = ...;` then with `foreach (var node in nodes) { }` the `var` will mean `string`, not `object` there. `foreach` uses a kind of duck typing.

Answer (score 2):

[As I found out recently myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16421852/c-sharp-type-conversion-inconsistent), the foreach loop does an explicit cast to the type of the element variable. This comes from the time before C# 2.0, where generics were introduced.

```
List myList = getStringList();
foreach (string element in myList)
{
    // ...
}
```

Even though `myList` is just a `List`, not generic, and therefore only contains objects, I know that it contains strings, and can just do this foreach loop, which will add the explicit cast for me.

Enter generics. Suddenly you do not need that anymore, but it is still part of the language.

```
List<string> myList = getStringList();
foreach (string element in myList)
{
    // ...
}
```

However, this can now have terrible pitfalls:

```
List<long> myLongList = getLongList();
foreach (int element in myLongList)
{
    // ...
}
```

This will produce no error, no warning, no runtime exception. Even though I casted longs to ints without checking. There is a good chance I have just corrupted my data. Ouch. How to avoid that?

By using `var`, as you did.

```
List<long> myLongList = getLongList();
foreach (var element in myLongList)
{
    // ...
}
```

Now, no matter what the element type of the list is, my `element` variable will be of the same type. Yay!

Where this falls short, is when working with non-generic APIs, such as the `XmlNode`. When you ask it for its child nodes, you get a non-generic list. If you now use `var` on it, there is no way for the system to know that this list only contains `XmlNode` instances. All it can do, really, is go the non-generic way, and turn that `var` into `object`.

In short, your first `foreach` statement works fine because of the implicit explicit cast (as I have come to call it in my mind). The second one fails, because without that cast, there is no type information but `object`.