# C# DataSet foreach

Tags: c#, foreach, dataset

I'm using DataSet and when I iterate at columns with foreach loop I can't get ColumnName (if using var keyword):

e.g.

```
DataTable table1 = new DataTable("patients");
table1.Columns.Add("name");
table1.Columns.Add("id");
table1.Rows.Add("sam", 1);
table1.Rows.Add("mark", 2);
```

And than using foreach:

[image]

But if foreach statement is explicitly defined:

[image]

Everything is ok.
I know that foreach is syntactic sugar for Enumarator.
Is it some kind of legacy and lack of Generics ?

Comment: This is not uncommon.  My VS 2017 RC will treat your code like the object is a column, but my VS 2015 copy I find I have to cast explicitly or declare type in the foreach.  I think this is more an IDE issue than anything.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto It's `object` because the code was written in C# 1.0 and they didn't have better options, not because the columns aren't actually all `DataColumn` instances.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why var used in foreach for XmlNode does not deduce real type, only object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106986/why-var-used-in-foreach-for-xmlnode-does-not-deduce-real-type-only-object)

Comment: Never knew foreach would cast for you. Neat. Ish.

Comment: @Will It's mostly just annoying, post C# 1.0.  It only existed to deal with the fact that, without generics, every data structure returned `object` instances, so you *always* needed to cast them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataTable.Columns is a DataColumnCollection. DataColumnCollection implements IEnumerable, not IEnumerable<DataColumn>. The foreach statement performs a cast for whichever type you specify. Var specifies what the enumerator method returns (which is this case is Object).

Comment: IEnumerable, not IEnumerable.
Guess you mean IEnumerator.
But why it's casting to object / usually var got object type ?

Comment: The answer here is stating that it implements the standard `IEnumerable` and not the generic `IEnumerable<T>`. This means that iterating through DataTable.Columns would return objects of type `object` unless you coerce them to another type (DataColumn) by doing something like `foreach (DataColumn column in table1.Columns)`

Answer (score 0):

> Is it some kind of legacy and lack of Generics?

Yes.  This code was written in C# 1.0, before generics existed.